# Regular Expression in C# for either empty, 0, or a length 5 digit. (Zip Code)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm stuck on this problem. I have an input field for a zip code, however, our database has a lot of records where the zip code is 0. I currently have a regular expression set on the field to ensure that the zip is either empty or is a 5 digit value.

Because this however, if you go to update a record that has the value set to "0", it triggers a validation message because it is not an empty string or a 5 digit string. I want to make it be able to accept all three of these states (empty, "0" or a 5 digit number).

(^\s{0,5}$)|(^\d{5}$) - This is what I've been using for the empty or 5 digit number, it seems to work fine.

(^?:(\s{0}$)|(^?:(0){1}$|\d{5})$) - I've tried this for the empty, "0" or 5 digit number, but it doesn't work. I really have next to no clue what's going on, I barely understand regular expressions. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ReGex is used to match patterns, you can't match something that isn't there - you should be using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` for that.

Comment: Can the 5 digit number be "00000"?

Comment: Do your field have blanck spaces? Try `(^\s{0,5}(?:0)?$)|(^\d{5}$)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with:

```
(^([0]|[0-9]{5})$)
```

Where the input is 0 or any 5 number combination.

As pointed out in the comment, regex is for matching and you can't match when there is nothing

Comment: That did the trick. This is working exactly the way I want it to! Thanks.

Comment: This won't match an empty string.  Add an optional qualifier: `^(0|[0-9]{5})?$`

Answer (score 2):

Dont use Regex to check for empty string:

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)
{
    // String is empty, do something.
    Console.WriteLine("No string here!");
}
else
{
    // Do Regex here
}
```

Comment: Indeed you can't, really, because a regex for an empty string matches *all* strings. :)

Comment: tbh I've never tried to match an empty string in regex anyway because I've never used a language that can't check for `Null` or `Empty` but you learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

You will always want to match the start and end of the string, so you won't need these in the Regex groups. As for the shorthand character '\s', this merely represents a space.

What you will want to match:

- Empty string
- Single zero
- Five-digit number

To this end, the following should hopefully work:

^(\s{0}|0|\d{5})$

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexrp `(^$)|0|\d{5}`

but `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `int.Parse()` are preferred.